# Jira Creating Task - Insert Table with JavaScript into description field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, automation

I am creating an extension for jira.

This extension basically clicks create and then fill the areas.

[image]

Since jira uses a client-side app here, basic querySelector('input').innerText won't work.

That's why I use document.execCommand('insertText') to fill the areas.

I have a HTML table element and when I select the table with my mouse then paste it into the descripion field, Jira automatically render the table

[image]

I tried to paste HTML code into descripion field, It didn't render.

Then, I realized that jira supports markdown. So I've converted my html table into a markdown table, which when I manually copy and paste it, It renders the table.

But document.execCommand('insertText') doesn't work here..

[image]

```
let markdownTable = `
| Syntax      | Description |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| Header      | Title       |
| Paragraph   | Text        |
`
let el = document.querySelector("[aria-label='Main content area']")
el.focus()
document.execCommand("insertText", false, markdownTable)
el.dispatchEvent(new Event("change", { bubbles: true }))
```

[image]

It render them as `<p>` elements. Is there any way to simulate manual copy & paste, or any other workaround for this?

Dispatching keyboard events didn't work me either.(trying to paste text)

```
let el2 = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Main content area"]')
el2.focus()
var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    bubbles : true,
    cancelable : true,
    char : "V",
    key : "v",
    ctrlKey : true,
    keyCode : 86
});
el2.dispatchEvent(e)
```

I am not sure if it helps but element is an contenteditable area ->
[image]

Comment: Try dispatching more keyboard events, [example](/a/69761966/).

Comment: It didn't work for me. I even tried with other chars, it didn't append them either.